Neutral in electrical receptacle
I have a concrete house with 1/2 inch metal conduits within the walls. One day I decided to test my washing machine with an electrical polarity/ground tester and noticed that hot and neutral were reversed. My laundry room is on the second floor. When I opened the receptacle I noticed that it was indeed reversed and the neutral was connected to ground via the metal electrical box.
I remembered almost a decade ago when they installed my minisplits on the roof and passed Line 1 and line 2 through that electrical box which has another metal conduit that goes to the roof. When they did that they tried to fish a 10 AWG wire and I helped them pull it to the electrical box, but I may have pulled too hard and a metal part holding the wire to the fish line broke off inside the conduit. I guess that's why they decided to bond both the mini splits and washer receptacle to ground through the electrical box.
I borrowed a plastic fish tape to feed the wire, but it seems to get snagged on the metal part inside the conduit and can't get it to the breaker box. Is there any other way to get the neutral wire through or can I use thinner guage wire parralleled together?

Why are they running 10 AWG wires through the conduit?  You're allowed to have up to 3 circuits per conduit (4 if they're all <=28A).  There should be a black*-white for the washer and a blue*-blue* for the mini-split, with conduit as ground, and possibly a green ground size of the largest wire.  If the mini-split is MCA <=20A, they can all be #12.  * Suggestions only. Hot colors can be anything but white, gray or green but must be clearly identified by circuit.

If you tug hard on the wires at each end, can you move them back and forth?  About an inch will suffice to establish clearance. I expect the fishing failed because fishing additional wires into an already populated conduit is really hard, and it jams A LOT and is often not possible.

You can't parallel conductors that small. The proper way to pull additional wire in a conduit is to pull all the existing wire out and pull them all, existing and additional, at the same time. You take a big chance of damaging the insulation trying to due it separately.

I'm afraid if I remove the 3 cables currently in the conduit from the breaker box to the electrical receptacle in the laundry that I won't be able to put them back in, but I understand what you mean and I'm fearing that it may be a possibility if I keep trying to yank the fish tape.

What are the cables sizes and the distance from the breaker box to the outlet?  There are cable pulling lubricants out there to assist in pulling cables.

The 3 wires are 10 AWG and about 20 feet.

You should have very ittle trouble pulling 4 #10 THHN/THWN wires 20 feet in 1/2" conduit.   If your wire is stranded, it will pull easier.

There is the issue of whatever is stuck inside the conduit.

I was planning on rewiring the mini splits from the roof to the side of the house to another sub panel is have in the garage next to the electrical meter that I had installed. Can I run just the neutral wire from that subpanel to the laundry receptacle or would the distance difference be too much?  It will most likely be more than 20 feet.

Whatever is stuck will probably come out if you remove the wires.  The neutral needs to be run with it's hots.
